# formatting string in python with class members

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
class Foo:
  def geta(self):
    self.a = 'lie'
    return 'this is {self.a}'.format(?)
```

What should I write instead of the question mark so that the string will be formatted correctly?

Comment: `'this is {}'.format (self.a)`

Comment: ok, but assume I would like to have the variable name inside my string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you probably are looking for is

```
'this is {0.a}'.format(self)
'this is {.a}'.format(self)
'this is {o.a}'.format(o=self)
'this is {self.a}'.format(self=self)
```

Note, however, that you are missing at least a method in your class.

Directly under the class scope there is no such thing as `self`.

Comment: It is best to explicitly address the referenced object with `{0.a}` or similar. `{.a}` works only once. It fails otherwise like in: `"'this is {.a}, i repeat myself {.a}'.format(self)'"`.

Comment: @tssch But if you do `this is {.a}, i repeat myself {.a}'.format(self, self)`, it works. The first `self` is for the first `{.a}`, the second one for the second one. As documented.

Answer (score 4):

The reference you include inside the brackets refers to either a number indicating the index of the argument passed to format, or a name directing to a named argument in the format call. Like that:

```
class Foo:
  def geta(self):
    self.a = 'lie'
    return 'this is {self.a}'.format(self=self)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; just fix your code example to actually include a method definition, as OP's example is broken.

Comment: hmm, what about using something like format(self.__dict__) or something along those lines so one could easily format with all class members?